# Parsing email file with mime4J

Tags: java, mime4j

I found this example for parsing an email:
http://www.mozgoweb.com/posts/how-to-parse-mime-message-using-mime4j-library/

But the example is not working, because import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message; is not working.

How can I create a Message from a file?

```
 MessageImpl mimeMsg = new MessageImpl();
 //Get some standard headers
 System.out.println("To: " + mimeMsg.getTo().toString());
 System.out.println("From: " + mimeMsg.getFrom().toString());
 System.out.println("Subject: " + mimeMsg.getSubject());
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Did you setup the dependency properly?

Comment: The problem is, that the import import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message; is not working. Message is not known. Others imports like import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyPart is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this jar in your classpath:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j/0.6.1/apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar

Dependency For maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Now I have another problem: I am getting this error: NoSuchMethodError on new Message(fis). fis is a file input stream

Comment: @Peter .. I downloaded the jar, extracted and can see the constructor `public Message(InputStream is)`. Are you doing the right import `org.apache.james.mime4j.message` ?

Comment: Yes, import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message;  even tried new org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message(fis)

Comment: @Peter Are you getting on run-time or its not letting you compile it?

Comment: @Peter check if you may have two version of mime4j jars?

Comment: I am getting a runtime exception, it compiles without problems. I have just one version of the jar file in my class path

Comment: @Peter ...but you are using new MessageImpl()... It seems to be coming from else where... Can you post relevant details? Code n stracktrace

Comment: My code:   Message mimeMsg
            try {
                mimeMsg = Message(fis)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                println e
            }

            //Get some standard headers
            System.out.println("To: " + mimeMsg.getTo().toString());  

Exception: 

..groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovytests.HelpController.Message() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.FileInputStream) values:

Comment: Was missing new statement, now I get following error:

Caused by NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeStreamParser.<init>(Lorg/apache/james/mime4j/parser/MimeEntityConfig;)V
->>  139 | <init>    in org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message